# Lighting an instantiated prefab, baked versus realtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, real-time

I'm generating a dungeon out of prefabs which means I design a room, save it in the resource folder and instantiate it at a random position with a random rotation while the game is running.

The problem I have is the lighting.

Because of the above mentioned generation process it has to be dynamic but it doesn't seem to work. Below you can see the comparison between a baked and realtime rendered room:

Baked (I also don't know where these strange lighting borders (on the walls), which are looking like someone painted the light with watercolors are coming from):

[image: Backed]

Realtime:

[image: Realtime]

As you can see, the realtime room doesn't seem to reflect light in any way.
These are my lighting settings:

[image: Settings]

And this is my 'sun':
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just FYI that is spelled "Lighting".  (in english "lightning" is the electrical stuff during a storm)  cheers!

Comment: just to make sure , you have the lights right? where did you put the lights?

Comment: Added a screenshot, I only have 1 directional light

Comment: Without actually having the project it looks from your settings like you're just missing Ambient intensity & build. Unity uses precomputed realtime GI so some information still needs building. Are you using the standard PBS?

Comment: Also the "lighting borders" on the baked GI are called banding, this is a side effect of baking because it rasterizes the lighting to a lightmap (texture). It's a compromise for performance espescially if you're targeting mobile

Answer (score 2):

Your lighting settings have Ambient Light set  to 0- with realtime lighting, this means nothing that can directly see the source of a light will be lit at all. The screenshot with baked lighting looks different because it has a baked lightmap.

If you're trying to get the real-time lighting to look exactly like the baked, soyy, but Unity refuses to bake lightmaps at runtime. The closest you can probably get is by setting your Ambient Light to a color and its intensity above zero. Playing around with Light Probes probably won't be much good, since you need to light an entire room in a vacuum.

An alternate solution, depending on how well you know Unity, would be to Frankenstein together different scenes, which is mentioned briefly in Unity's Intro to Global Illumination, though I can't find it anywhere else.

Relevant links:

Baked Lightmaps: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GIIntro.html

Light Probes: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightProbes.html

Ambient Light: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GlobalIllumination.html

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have already read nearly every piece of Unity's documentation on lightning but I thought I missed something, as it's really easy to make a good looking, realtime illuminated scene in UE4. I also found [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/problems-with-instantiating-baked-prefabs.324514/) thread, but I couldn't get it working...
Do you know if this will be easier in future Unity versions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.